# Ext.js grid filter not triggering

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm new to Ext.js but for a customer I'm looking into their grid code in an effort to get their column filtering working properly.  The grids by default are using the string filter on most columns.  I was able to update a column for testing to use a list filter.  On the front end, this appears initially to work as both the string filter and list filter display as expected. The issue is that once the filter is selected (or text entered in the string box filter), nothing happens.  No filter is triggered, no messages on the console. Nothing.  I'm not sure where to start to troubleshoot this. Seems like it must be a global issue with the code that is creating the grid (which is centralized).  The following components are located in their Ext.require statement:

```
Ext.require([
'Ext.data.*', 
'Ext.grid.*',
'Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer',
'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature',
'Ext.ux.form.SearchField',
'Ext.toolbar.Paging']);
```

Without including the entire code (which is spread out into multiple libraries) any suggestions on where to focus my troubleshooting efforts?

VERSION 4.2.2 of Sencha Ext.js

Comment: You shouldn't dive head first into spaghetti code spread over a dozen libraries. You should start by implementing and debugging the required feature in a small sencha fiddle. That's around 100 lines, give or take. After that, take each property you set in the fiddle and check for its existence in the big code.

Comment: In the fiddle, you will have to check for compatibility between Paging, Buffered Renderer and Filters Feature.

Comment: Did you wanted to filter record locally or remotely?

Comment: I would like to filter locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. The issue was that in the grid store definition there was a call to a filterBy method which was returning true in all cases.  I suspect this was overriding any filtering results I was attempting with the string filter.Removing the call to that method had the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

In grid you have to add this config

```
 features: [{
    ftype: 'filters',
    local: true
}]
```

You can also see running examples and code in this link.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#big-data-grid

Comment: Yes, I believe this is set as you have indicated.